# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)" using Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, json, express

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https") ;

const app = express();

// keep static files (e.g css,image files) inside a folder called 'Public'
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})) ;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app.html") ;
});

app.post( "/", (req, res) => {
    const firstName = req.body.fName ;
    const lastName = req.body.lName ;
    const email = req.body.eMail ;
    let data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_fields: {
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME:lastName
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = "https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/0457e81530";
    const options = {
        method: "POST" ,
        auth: "Jewel:a940bdffbeedd3146d8722711e7c4e98-us7"
    }
    const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
        response.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        })
    });
    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end;
});

app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("server is running on port 3000") ;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <p> <input name="fName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required> </p>
        <p> <input name="lName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required> </p>
        <p> <input name="eMail" type="email" placeholder="email" required> </p>
        <p><button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button></p>

    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my error in the CLI
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

```sh
server is running on port 3000
undefined:1
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jewel\Documents\HMDT ADF\getting started\PR0JECT_1\nodejs\form\app.js:42:34)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:519:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:992:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:973:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: What is the value of data (without JSON.parse)?

Comment: @Michiel, here is what I got  "<Buffer 3c 48 54 4d 4c 3e 3c 48 45 41 44 3e 3c 54 49 54 4c 45 3e 45 72 72 6f 72 3c 2f 54 49 54 4c 45 3e 3c 2f 48 45 41 44 3e 3c 42 4f 44 59 3e 0a 41 6e 20 65 ... 125 more bytes>" they are hexadecimal codes as I learnt

Comment: 1. You are importing the `request` module, but you are doing the actual request with `https`. Which one would you like to use? 2. You now log something on "data", but that does not mean all data is received yet 3. I would remove the "auth" token in your post. 4. I would use the `node-fetch` module, since `request` is deprecated and the `https` module is a more often used for requests with more low level configurations. Please let me know if you the docs of node-fetch are not clear enough and you need more help.

Comment: @Michiel I appreciate your response, pls I would like to read docs on "node-fetch"

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep using the `https` module:

```
const request = https.request(url, options, (response) => {
  let data = '';
  response.on("data", (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  response.on("end", () => {
    const result = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong.
Use the postman app and post that url and you'll see your getting back an error page.

I believe your missing "/members" at the end.
Add to your options "body: data"
and your data should not be an array, just the object (this was an error I found after dealing with the 2 suggestions above).